# Differences between Kubernetes Layer 7 and Layer 4 Cloud Load Balancers

Tags: kubernetes

My understanding is that if you deploy a Kubernetes service of type 'LoadBalancer' then the Kubernetes cloud controller will automatically provision a Layer 4 load balancer in the cloud you're using. So this would imply that any Kubernetes service of type 'LoadBalancer' always maps to a Layer 4 cloud load balancer, correct?

However, my understanding of the Kubernetes Ingress is that once you deploy your Ingress controllers you also need to provision a service of type 'LoadBalancer' to route traffic to the Ingress controller pods. But this time, since an Ingress is involved, the load balancer will be provisioned as a Layer 7 load balancer and that Layer 7 load balancer sits in front of your Kubernetes cluster and routes traffic to your Ingress controllers.

So it looks like the Kubernetes cloud controller determines whether to provision a Layer 7 or Layer 4 load balancer based on whether an Ingress is present or not. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Ingresses & Ingress-Controller**

A Kubernetes service is by default exclusive to the cluster.
Only applications running on the cluster can access them because of this.
An ingress in Kubernetes allows us to direct traffic from outside the cluster to ***one or more*** services there.
For all incoming traffic, the ingress typically serves as a single point of entry.
An ingress is assigned a public IP address (provisioned by your cloud provider), making it reachable from outside the cluster.
It then directs all of its traffic to the proper service using a set of rules, however, most Ingress-Controllers directly serve traffic to the pods and not through the service (by constantly checking the endpoint object).

When creating an ingress, there are a few things to consider.
They are initially made to manage web traffic (HTTP or HTTPS).
Although it is possible, using an ingress with other kinds of protocols usually requires additional configuration. Most importantly, the ingress object doesn't actually accomplish anything on its own. Therefore, we must have an ingress controller on hand for an ingress to actually function. Most cloud platforms provide their own ingress controllers, but there are also plenty of open-source options to choose from.

**LoadBalancer**

Ingresses and LoadBalancers in Kubernetes overlap quite a bit.
This is due to the fact that they are primarily employed to expose services to the internet.

LoadBalancers, however, differ from ingresses in several ways, a load balancer is merely an addition to a service, not a separate entity like an ingress.
For this to work, the cluster must be running on a provider that supports external load balancers. All of the major cloud providers support external load balancers using their own resource types:

- AWS uses a Network Load Balancer
- GKE also uses a Network Load Balancer
- Azure uses a Public Load Balancer

Load balancers can only route to a single service because they are defined per service. As opposed to an ingress, which can route to numerous services within the cluster, this is different. As you've noted, a LoadBalancer operatores on Layer 4 whereas most Ingress Controllers operate on Layer 7; however the Ingress-Controller is usually "exposed" by an external Layer 4 LB to make it accessible in the first place.

---

That being said, your Cloud-provider doesn't decide wether to create an Ingress or LoadBalancer, it obviously depends on what resource you're creating and your CNI (Container Network Interface), which most Cloud providers also have their own implementation will notify the necessary service to create the resource you want. Also, keep in mind that regardless of the provider, using an external LoadBalancer will typically come with additional costs.

Answer (score 0):

**Layer-4** load balancer (or the external load balancer) forwards traffic to Nodeports. It allows you to forward both HTTP and TCP traffic. In Layer 4 Services can be exposed through a single globally managed config-map.

**Layer-7** makes smart and informed load balances based on the content of the data,however, layer 4 carries out its load balancing based on its inbuilt software algorithm. Its load balancing is more CPU‑intensive than packet‑based Layer 4 load balancing, but rarely causes degraded performance on a modern server. Layer 7 load balancing enables the load balancer to make smarter load‑balancing decisions, and to apply optimizations and changes to the content.
Some cloud-managed layer-7 load balancers (such as the ALB ingress controller on AWS) expose DNS addresses for ingress rules. You need to map (via CNAME) your domain name to the DNS address generated by the layer-7 load balancer. Google Load Balancer provides a single routable IP address. Nginx Ingress Controller exposes the external IP of all nodes that run the Nginx Ingress Controller. You can configure your own DNS to map (via A records) your domain name to the IP addresses exposed by the Layer-7 load balancer.

**Kubernetes Ingress** is a collection of routing rules that govern how external users access services running on the Kubernetes cluster. **Ingress controller** reads the ingress resource’s information and processes the data accordingly. So basically, ingress resources contain the rules to route the traffic and ingress controller routes the traffic.

Routing using ingress is not standardized i.e. different ingress controllers have different semantics (different ways of routing).

At the end of the day, you need to build your own ingress controller based on your requirements and implementations. Ingress is the most flexible and configurable routing feature available.

**Please look at the table below for more details :**

[image]